# java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection problem on android studio and ionicframeword windows 7

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ionic-framework

I am trying to build a mobile application,firstly i used ionic framework but i got this response 
    java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection

then i switch to android studio, after successful building two apps on the  third attempt 
i got this response

`````
````The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.````
`````

so i debug it with `gradlew ---stacktrace` from the android studio terminal here is my resul

`````html
````C:\Users\User\AndroidStudioProjects\nmm>gradlew --stacktrace
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 busy Daemon could not be reused, use --s
tatus for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with -
-scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.UncheckedIOException: java.io.IOException: Unable to
establish loopback connection
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedEx
ception(UncheckedException.java:57)
        at org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException.throwAsUncheckedEx
ception(UncheckedException.java:40)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection
.<init>(SocketConnection.java:61)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnectCom
pletion.create(SocketConnectCompletion.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.
connectToDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:262)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.
connectToDaemonWithId(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:248)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.
doStartDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:215)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.
startDaemon(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:204)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DefaultDaemonConnector.
connect(DefaultDaemonConnector.java:128)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Da
emonClient.java:138)
        at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(Da
emonClient.java:92)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction
.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute
(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAnd
BuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:285)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAnd
BuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:258)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(
ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(
ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogg
ing.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:251)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogg
ing.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:185)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.j
ava:45)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Metho
d)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(
ProcessBootstrap.java:60)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(Proces
sBootstrap.java:37)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Metho
d)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Sourc
e)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown S
ource)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMa
inStarter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecuto
r.java:108)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMa
in.java:61)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connect
ion
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method
)
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown S
ource)
        at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection
$SocketInputStream.<init>(SocketConnection.java:155)
        at org.gradle.internal.remote.internal.inet.SocketConnection
.<init>(SocketConnection.java:59)
        ... 32 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source)
        at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(Unk
nown Source)
        ... 43 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org ```
`````

my java version is uptodate
android studio version3.2
am using windows 7 professional ,64bits 
please help out ,i am unable to build mobile apps

i have search google but there seems to be no successful answer